# Is it possible to use an object field as part of regex rule?

Tags: formula, validation-rule

Let's say I'm looking to use the state abbreviation as part of a validation rule, for example, California: CA-1111.

I'm trying the following logic but it's not returning the desired output.

```
NOT(REGEX(FIELD, "State-[0-9]{4}"))
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the String Concatenation ("`&`") operator:

```
NOT(REGEX(FIELD, State & "-[0-9]{4}"))
```